# WPF - persist tag property on image, to say a PNG File on disk

Tags: wpf, image, tags

I have a simple WPF application. In there, I have an image control - `system.windows.control.images`, lets call it `x:Name="myImage"`. I have 
png files on disk, that I display in that control. I do this by creating 
`BitampImage` object from the PNG file path

```
BitmapImage myBMP = new BitmapImage();
...
myBMP.UriSource = new Uri(PNGFilePath)
...
myImage.Source = myBMP;
```

After my workflows, I write data to the `TagProperty` of that Image in the control

```
myImage.SetValue(TagProperty, DateTime.UtcNow.Day)
```

The Tag does get updated with the value I write, but that's just in the 
`myImage`; I want to write this tag value into the source PNG file, is it 
possible to do ?

I tried :-

```
BitmapEncoder myEncoder = null;
myEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
BitmapFrame myBMPFrame = BitmapFrame.Create((BitmapSource)myImage.Source);
myEncoder.Frames.Add(myBMPFrame);
string FileName = "C:\\ImageTest\\myTestFile.png";
using (var stream = File.Create(FileName))
{
    objEncoder.Save(stream);
}
```

After this `FileName` is saved, I load it, but when I look for the `TagProperty` it is `null`. What am I missing ?

Comment: You may look for EXIF tags. You should find some information with this keyword.

Comment: The BitmapImage doesn't know anything about the Tag property of the Image element, so obviously you have to manage this yourself. What is the purpose of the timestamp? You can perhaps just set the file's creation time, write time or last access time.

Comment: As a note, there is a BitmapImage constructor that takes an Uri argument, so that you don't need to call BeginInit/EndInit: `var myBMP = new BitmapImage(new Uri(PNGFilePath));`